# PHP 7.3 / print_r($GLOBALS) causes "Fatal error: Allowed memory size"

Tags: php, memory, size

We've just upgraded to PHP 7.3 and are experiencing some strange behaviour.

When I try to run the following code PHP crashes with the error message

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 534777856 bytes) in /............./test.php on line 2
```

Code:

```
<?php
print_r($GLOBALS);
?>
```

As you see it's a really simple script with only one line of code. var_export works and shows the content correctly. Increasing the memory limit only delays the crash. In PHP 5.6 it's working as it's supposed to.

Did any of you experience the same behaviour with PHP 7.3? Do you have any tips apart from not using print_r?

Thanks

PS: That's the correct output of var_export, so $GLOBALS is really far away from being as big as suggested in the error message:

```
array(5) { ["_GET"]=> array(0) { } ["_POST"]=> array(0) { } ["_COOKIE"]=> array(3) { ["xxxx_username"]=> string(4) "xxxx" ["printcounter"]=> string(1) "4" ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(32) "793b64887bb8b857515748bbb3d7c5cb" } ["_FILES"]=> array(0) { } ["GLOBALS"]=> array(5) { ["_GET"]=> array(0) { } ["_POST"]=> array(0) { } ["_COOKIE"]=> array(3) { ["xxxx_username"]=> string(4) "xxxx" ["printcounter"]=> string(1) "4" ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(32) "793b64887bb8b857515748bbb3d7c5cb" } ["_FILES"]=> array(0) { } ["GLOBALS"]=> *RECURSION* } }
```

Comment: no, this is a php default recursion. $GLOBALS is a part of itself - has always been. And: I couldn't change this, it's only one line of code. This has been working since the dawn of time :-)

Comment: Seems like a 7.3 bug. https://3v4l.org/AdLgJ

Comment: thanks... I've posted a bug report for the developers.